# Why MediaPlayer stops on app restart state in android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I made a soundboard app and it works but when i press home button on phone and
I click to bring app back ,when i press a button for the sound it stops working(crashes)

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iaminevitable);

        iaminevitable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iaminevitable);
        iaminevitable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
```

**My Error Logcat =**

```
Process: soundboard.test, PID: 5429
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at soundboard.test.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:96)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you given the required permissions? check for it and please add some more code to the storage etc or if the problem is activity lifecycle just add this code

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
     recreate();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: this is the MainActivity and this is all of the codes in it i have more codes but they're the same mp2,mp3 etc, i'm a beginner so i'm not sure what kind of permissions do i have to add.

Comment: check this code and try to understand things like how mediaplayer is working how permissions are given etc https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/audio-recording-android-example/

Comment: The code worked now it doesn't crash anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The media player is set to null when the application goes to background, but not recreated when the activity is brought again to foreground (`onCreate()` is not called).
You should handle the initialization and destruction of objects in paired callbacks of the lifecycle, like

- `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`
- `onStart()` and `onStop()`
- `onResume()` and `onPause()`

Comment: Is there any chance you could write me a single lines of the code if you have some time since i'm not sure how to implement that in my code i would be really grateful.

Comment: for example you could move the `mp = ...` line to `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

You should understand `activity lifecycle` and permissions needed for audio files.
If I were you, I'd use below permissions.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

In `onCreate()`, you should initialize and destroy in `onDestroy()` method. Check which method is called when an app goes to background. Learn. Here is a link to [learn about activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

add onResume method as below

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mp != null) {
                //if want to start again when open app
                mp.start();

                //play when click button
    //            iaminevitable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //                @Override
    //                public void onClick(View view) {
    //                    mp.start();
    //                }
    //            });
            }
        }
```